# Integral of a product of Bessel functions of the first kind

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, bessel-functions, wolfram-alpha, approximate-integration

I want to do this integral $H(\rho)=\int_{0}^{\infty} J_1(2 \pi Lr)J_0(2\pi \rho r)dr$, where $J_1$ and $J_0$ are Bessel functions of the first kind and $L\in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant, so I tried to do this in the Mathematica, but he failed. When I tried to put some value to $L$ and $\rho$, the software calculate numerically, so I ploted $H(\rho)$ for a fixed $L$  and the result of the plot is a function like $rect(x/L)$, such that

\begin{equation}
{\displaystyle \operatorname {rect} (t)=\left\{{\begin{array}{rl}0,&{\text{if }}|t|>{\frac {1}{2}}\\{\frac {1}{2}},&{\text{if }}|t|={\frac {1}{2}}\\1,&{\text{if }}|t|<{\frac {1}{2}}.\end{array}}\right.}
 \end{equation}

I'm not sure about this result for $H(\rho)$, so I searched in the internet and didn't find none property  for solve this integral, I don't know if, in fact $H(\rho)=rect(x/L)$ or something of this type. Someone knows if this result is correct? This integral have an analytic solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general relationship you need is [Eqn. 10.22.63 in the Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22#E63):
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}J_{\mu}\left(ax\right)J_{\mu-1}\left(bx\right)\mathrm{d}x=%
\begin{cases}b^{\mu-1}a^{-\mu},&0<b<a,\\
(2b)^{-1},&b=a(>0),\\
0,&0<a<b,\end{cases}
$$
assuming $\Re(\mu) > 0$.

In your case, $a = 2 \pi L$, $b = 2 \pi \rho$, and $\mu = 1$.  The result you found above is what you'd get if you set $a = 1$ and $b = t$.

While the given equation seems to require positive $a$ and $b$, I believe you can extend the result to all real non-zero $a$ and $b$ by changing the variable of integration $t \to - t$ and/or using the property that $J_n(-x) = (-1)^n J_n(x)$.